# Sorting in Laravel using Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, sql-order-by, relational

How to apply sorting in eloquent query with relational table with "hasOne" Relation?

Brand Model

```
class Brand extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'brand';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['brand_name'];
    public $sortable = ['brand_name'];

    public function brandModel() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Brandmodel', 'brand_id')
                        ->select('id', 'brand_id', 'brand_model_name');
    }
}

---------------------------------------

class Brandmodel extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'brandmodel';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['brand_id'];
    public $sortable = ['brand_model_name'];
}
```

In this case we can sort using "brand_name". But I am not able to sort using "brand_model_name".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this you'll need to step outside of Eloquent a little bit and join on the table you need.

```
Brand::join('brandmodel', 'brandmodel.brand_id', '=', 'brand.id')
    ->orderBy('brandmodel.brand_model_name')
    ->get();
```

I'd also recommend you re-work your table names to match Eloquent's default naming conventions as it would make the code a little easier to parse.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, But I am expecting is it possible with "Fully Eloquent"

Comment: This just uses Eloquent's query builder to join the table, it's not possible to do this using the relationship method you've set up. This is as "Eloqent-ly" as you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Brand::leftJoin('brandmodel', 'brandmodel.brand_id', '=', 'brand.id')
    ->orderBy('brandmodel.brand_model_name','desc')
    ->get();
```